# is there an equivalent to 'classname.this' from java in c++?

Tags: java, c++, function, virtual, member

i am trying to call a private derived class method from a virtual function, but i cannot figure out how to call functions of the derived class from the virtual function.

This is the virtual function declaration in the Game class in Game.h

```
virtual void Screen::KeyListener::onChar(char c);
```

when i define this function in different .cpp file i cannot figure out how to access any of the methods declared in the Game class. I can only call functions from the Screen class.

i have tried stuff like this

```
Game::makeMove(1);
```

(where make move is private member function defined in the Game class)

but this just gives me the error "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object."

sorry if my wording/terminology is a little off, i am still quite new to c++. Most of my experience is with java.

Comment: Speak classes, not files. You can make a MCVE with just one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the definition is actually defining function onChar in class Game and not in class Screen? If you accidentally wrote this as the definition for onChar (which I can imagine could easily happen):

```
void Screen::KeyListener::onChar(char c) {}
```

then you are defining function in class Screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with use of static  like below code:

> Static Member Functions
>
> These functions work for the class as whole rather than for a
>   particular object of a class.
>
> It can be called using an object and the direct member access .
>   operator. But, its more typical to call a static member function by
>   itself, using class name and scope resolution :: operator.

Example :

```
class X
{
 public:
 static void f(){};
};

int main()
{
 X::f();   // calling member function directly with class name
}
```

These functions cannot access ordinary data members and member functions, but only static data members and static member functions.

It doesn't have any "this" keyword which is the reason it cannot access ordinary members.